# Is there anything like Quantopian in R?

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies

Quantopian is an incredible tool for the quant community, but it is Python based only.

Just wondering if is there anything like Quantopian in R that you reccommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an R interface to Quantopian Zipline called [flyingfox](https://github.com/DavisVaughan/flyingfox). Here is a [blog post](https://www.business-science.io/business-science-labs/2018/05/31/backtesting-quantopian-zipline-tibbletime-furrr-flyingfox.html) from its creator.